# syntax error, unexpected keyword_else, expecting end-of-input else ^

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I know that this has been answered before, but I've read through most of them and I still can't figure it out. Does someone know what's up?

```
<% if current_user.try(:email) == Join.all(:email) %>
      <div class="panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
          You're already signed up for this month! Thanks!
        </div>
      </div>
    <% else %>
      <% if user_signed_in? %>
        <%= form_for @join do |f| %>
          <%= f.email_field :email, value: current_user.email, class: "form-control input-lg", id: "join" %> <br>
          <%= f.submit "Join This Month's Rewards", class: "btn btn-success btn-lg" %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    <% else %>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Sorry, you're not currently signed in, so you can't sign up for our rewards. You can sign in <a href="/users/sign_in">here.</a>
      </div>
      </div>
  <% end %>
```

Here is the full error: `/Users/Sam/Documents/workspace/rewardsApp/app/views/joins/new.html.erb:19: syntax error, unexpected keyword_else, expecting keyword_end else ^` The error is on line 29, which is the `<% else %>` after the two `<% end %>`
Help is most appreciated!

Comment: You should provide the full error.

Comment: @Laurel I fixed it... Do you know what the issue is? I hate to ask for help, but I'm really stuck.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `if` / `else` setup is ending too early in order to account for three states of the view.

```
<% if current_user.try(:email) == Join.all(:email) %>
      <div class="panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
          You're already signed up for this month! Thanks!
        </div>
      </div>
    <% else %>
      <% if user_signed_in? %>
        <%= form_for @join do |f| %>
          <%= f.email_field :email, value: current_user.email, class: "form-control input-lg", id: "join" %> <br>
          <%= f.submit "Join This Month's Rewards", class: "btn btn-success btn-lg" %>
      <% else %>
          <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">
            Sorry, you're not currently signed in, so you can't sign up for our rewards. You can sign in <a href="/users/sign_in">here.</a>
          </div>
          </div>
      <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks @joncoud that worked. You forgot an <% end %> after the form. but other than that, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a good example of why indenting your code appropriately is very helpful.  Once you do, it becomes apparent that you have a second `else` clause.

```
<% if current_user.try(:email) == Join.all(:email) %>
  <div class="panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
      You're already signed up for this month! Thanks!
    </div>
  </div>
<% else %>
  <% if user_signed_in? %>
    <%= form_for @join do |f| %>
      <%= f.email_field :email, value: current_user.email, class: "form-control input-lg", id: "join" %> <br>
      <%= f.submit "Join This Month's Rewards", class: "btn btn-success btn-lg" %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% else %> <%# <= Uh oh, second else clause %>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
      Sorry, you're not currently signed in, so you can't sign up for our rewards. You can sign in <a href="/users/sign_in">here.</a>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```